# Hitting same controller url method manually gives error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to Codeigniter i am stuck into a problem, i have searched every where but i did not find solution to it,
My problem is when i hit a particular controller method through a link it works perfectly for eg.

`http://localhost/MyProject/indexController/user_login_process`

but when i hit that method manually after it renders first time properly, it renders view but following error is there.
Please help me to sort out my issue:

> Controller:

```
   public function user_login_process() {

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {


if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
$this->load->view('teaching');


}else{

$this->load->view('index');

}
} else {
$username=$this->input->post('username');
$data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),'password' => $this->input->post('password'));
$result = $this->login_database->login($data);
if ($result == TRUE) {


$result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($username);
if ($result != false) {

$session_data = array('id'=>$result[0]->id,'username' => $result[0]->email,'password' => $result[0]->password);

// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $session_data);

$user_info=$this->session->userdata('user_info');
$u_id=$user_info['id'];

$data['query']=$this->teaching_model->get_all_courses($u_id);
$this->load->view('teaching', $data);

}
} 
else 
{ 
$data = array('error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
$this->load->view('index', $data);
}
}
}
```

> Model:

```
<?php

Class Teaching_model extends CI_Model {

function get_all_courses($u_id)
{
   $condition = "u_id =" . "'" . $u_id . "'";
   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->select("*");
   $this->db->from("course");
   $this->db->where($condition);
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
}

}
```

> teaching View:

```
foreach ($query as $row) 
        { ?>
$row->name;
<? }  ?>
```

[image]

Comment: I think your $this->t_model->get_all($u_id); return null or empty array

Comment: Can you show your views and model?

Comment: When i go to this view by clicking on link it is rendering properly problem arises when i refresh it through url

Comment: Actually my view is too big it contains the data returned by controller and is working when i load it by clicking link

Comment: Problem arises when i reload page or refresh it by hitting url manually.

Comment: Add this 
print_r($query); exit; 
in the top of the view page and comment the reponse

Comment: This is the output : A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: views/teaching.php

Line Number: 1

Comment: @blacmoon- How will i get the query value when i refresh the page by hitting same url in the browser

Comment: problem might be with the session . , echo $u_id and check if it is empty while refreshing the page .

Comment: Can you edit your question with the view where the for each loop is and your model function

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Ok i am updating my question

Comment: @user3653474 show us your model and view

Comment: @wolfgang1983- I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. All codes are changed. check carefully.

Change your controller name to `Home.php` and inside `Home` too. Bcz your URL contain index is something feal bad

**In Controller**

```
public function user_login_process() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
    {
        # I dont know purpose od this. For now i juts redirct to login

        redirect('login');
    /*      if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
            {
                $this->load->view('teaching');
            }
            else
            {

                $this->load->view('index');

            }*/
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->load->database();

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $result = $this->login_database->login($username,$password);

        if ($result == 0) {
            echo "Invalid login";
        }
        elseif ($result == 1) {
            echo "Multiple account matched. Contact admin";
        }
        else{
            $session_data = array(
                'id' =>$result[0]['id'],
                'username' => $result[0]['email'],
                'password' => $result[0]['password'],
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            );
            # only set one sesstion
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

            $id = $result[0]['id']; # logged User ID
            $data['query']=$this->teaching_model->get_all_courses($id);
        }



        if ($result) 
        {
            $result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($username);
            if ($result != false) 
            {
                // Add user data in session
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $session_data);

                $user_info=$this->session->userdata('user_info');
                $u_id=$user_info['id'];

                $result2 =  $this->teaching_model->get_all_courses($u_id);

                if($result2 == 0){
                    echo "No Courses Found";
                }
                else{
                    $data['query'] = $result2;
                    $this->load->view('teaching', $data);
                }       
            }
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $data = array('error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
            $this->load->view('index', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

**In Model*(login_database)***

```
public function login($username,$password)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username = '$username' AND password= '$password' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count)) {
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($count) >1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**In Model*(Teaching_model)***

```
Class Teaching_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_all_courses($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE u_id = $id");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $count = count($result);

        if (empty($count)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is an issue with session, try using database for managing sessions:

**config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

**For MySQL:**

Create a table named 'ci_sessions' in your database, all the sessions will  be managed using this table, and it will help you when you are hosting the website / application , may avoid some possible errors with the session variables and the permissions  :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

**For Validating the users against their password **

```
public function validate_admin($username,$password)
    {
        // grab user input
        if(isset($_POST['username']) AND $_POST['username'] !='')
        {
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
        }



        $this->db->where('username', $username);

        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        $this->db->having("rec_status != 'C' ");
        // Run the query
        $query = $this->db->get('employee');
        // Let's check if there are any results
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            // If there is a user, then create session data
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
            'id_admin' => $row->id,
            'first_name' => $row->first_name,
            'last_name' => $row->last_name,
            'email_admin' => $row->email,
            'phone_admin' => $row->phone,
            'acc_status_admin' => $row->rec_status,
            'acc_type_admin' => $row->emp_role,
            'validated_admin' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }


        // If the previous process did not validate
        // then return false.
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want all the details to keep in session

Comment: I want to loop it in my view and fetch all the details this problem is occuring in all the pages of such type so how will i be able to keep every page info in session please provide another solution

Comment: I have checked there is nothing to do with the session.